# SOLR edismax search

Tags: search, solr, edismax

I have 2 documents in SOLR:

first

```
id = 125 
spell = Quanti disperati si rovescerebbero con i barconi sulle nostre coste...
```

second

```
id = 321 
spell = Quanti disperati si rovescerebbero con i barconi sulle nostre coste...
```

**http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q={!type=edismax qf=spell v='disperati si rovescerebbe*'}** - working fine for me, it returns 2 documents but how can I add to this query search by id too?

I need something like this:
**http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q={!type=edismax qf=spell v='disperati si rovescerebbe*'} & {!type=edismax qf=id v='125'}** - incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the id why not use -

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q={!type=edismax qf=spell v='disperati si rovescerebbe*'}&fq=id:125
```